# Firefox issue with scale and hardware accelerated transition

Tags: css, transform, scale, hardware-acceleration

This simple css animated transition works on chrome(27) but in firefox(21) jumps directly to the end.
Classes are applied sequentially via js.
Removing translateZ fixes firefox animation but I think it disables HW acceleration.
Question is, could be a ff bug or css is wrong?

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/geedmo/zUQax/

```
* {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.box.scale {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.box.scale.now {
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
}
// JS
$('.box').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('scale')
    this.offsetWidth
    $(this).addClass('now')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Scaling to a non zero value, but small enough to hide the item, works fine on firefox (23).

```
.box.scale.now {
  transform: scale(0.001);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.001);
}
```

It would be appreciated if someone know why it happens